# On the fly screen recorder and editor

Tags: video, ios, audio, screen-recording

I am looking for a free software similar to Sony Vegas Pro and GarageBand.
However, I do not need all the advanced editing tools for video and audio. Those are the features I need:

1. I want to capture iPad screen.
2. I want to capture audio from USB microphone.
3. Similar to Sony Vegas Pro, I want to edit audio without having to extract it from the video.
4. Similar to GarageBand, I want to record both audio and video on the fly, and to be able to go back and record a part once more in case I make a mistake.

I make tutorials using my iPad and iPencil.

My current solution is as follows:
- Connect iPad to Macbook.
- Connect USB microphone to Macbook.
- Record video using QuickTime Player.
- Simultaneously, record audio using Garageband.
- Put the audio and video together using iMovie.
- Edit using iMovie.

For a 20 minute video, I spend around 2 hours. Very inefficient.

Comment: I have added the iOS tag, since it seems you don't want an even more complex process involving Windows PC or similar. Feel free to rollback if that was an incorrect edit.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks! It's ideal for me to have a solution in iOS.